# countdown timer from mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have tried to create countdown timer from database. I have sent deltaTimeServer to JS. The output are right but they are freezing (not counting down, I have to press F5). Any idea for me?

Here is my code.

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function countDown(){  
     $(".show").each(function() {
          var elm = $(this);
          var difTime=this.timestamp;  
          var day=0,hours=0,minutes=0,seconds=0;  
          if(difTime>0){  
              day=Math.floor(difTime/84600);  
              hours=(Math.floor((difTime/3600))%24) + day*24 ;  
              minutes=Math.floor(difTime/60)%60;  
              seconds=Math.floor(difTime)%60;   
          }  
          else{  
              elm.removeClass("show"); //for remove class show
          }  
          elm.html(hours+' H '+minutes+' M '+seconds+' S ');  
      });
 }  
 function countDown_onLoad(){  
      $(".show").each(function() {
          this.timestamp = parseInt(this.firstChild.nodeValue,10);
      });
      setInterval(countDown,1000);
  }  
  $(document).ready(function() {  
      countDown_onLoad();  
  });  
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
$show=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `room_lists` WHERE `active` = 1");
while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($show))
{ 
   $timeStop = $array['timeStop'];
   $deltaTimeServer = strtotime($timeStop)-strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
   echo "<td align = 'center'><div class=\"show\">".$deltaTimeServer."</div></td>";
}
```

Comment: Check your browser console, perhaps a rogue exception is throwing off `setInterval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in you JS is that your difTime is always the same. You have to subtract the current timestamp from the original `this.timestamp`.

But, it's even easier since you're counting down every second. You can just decrement the timestamp:

```
var difTime=this.timestamp--;
```

And that should do it.

Also, you can change this:

```
$deltaTimeServer = strtotime($timeStop)-strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

To this:

```
$deltaTimeServer = strtotime($timeStop)-time();
```

Finally, I would hide the `td` with `style="display:none"` when you output it in PHP. Once the timestamp is set you can clear out the `td` and show it - this way people don't see a time stamp that turns into a counter.

Answer (score 0):

you should get new time stamp in function in setInterval.